# How to Fix Wordpress multisite woocommerce 403 file error

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, multisite, errors

Recently getting 403 error for woocommerce plugin files while accessing on frontend.
Frontend URL: https://tempserver.in/demo/haiko/
Used theme: ekommart

[image]

tried deactivating / re-activating plugins/ theme and also checked .htacess, but still no sucesss.
looking for guidance/ help advise here to fix.

Comment: Those are all served as static files, I think, directly from the web server and not through WordPress. Do they exist on disk in the right place, i.e. matching the request URLs, with permissions for the user that the web server is running as to read them?

Comment: Yes there are files, if i directly access through direct hit, i can open in browser